# How to protect plant from insects?

Tags: plants, insects

Here in the place plants are infected with the insects surrounding it and it affects the leaves and root too so decrease the life of plants.
So I want to know how to prevent this. Please suggest an idea.

Comment: Enviromesh? Might be an answer to many issues, not only insects ;)

Comment: This question would gain a lot if you could specify which plants and insects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***Here are some ways you can help protect your plants from insects:***

- Fertilize and water your plants regularly. Insects are less likely to infest healthy and well-nourished plants.
- Pull weeds around your plants as well. Insects such as aphids and
  stinkbugs feed on weeds; if they surround your plants, they're likely to attack them as well.
- Plant herbs and flowers around your plants. Basil helps ward off whiteflies, which are harmful to tomatoes, and oregano can help protect tomato and cucumber plants. Carrots and sunflowers help deter pests from your tomato plants. Nasturtiums and marigolds help protect both tomato and cucumber plants.
- Add natural predators. Soldier beetles, tachinid flies and braconid wasps feed on striped cucumber beetles, which can help protect your cucumber plants. Parasitic wasps will   help eliminate leafminers and stink bugs from your tomato plants.  Bigeyed bugs and minute pirate bugs attack tomato fruitworms that can destroy the fruit and stems of your tomato plants. Attract insect predators by growing plants that feature small flowers, such as daisies, dill and coneflower. These plants will encourage predators of insects and beneficial insects including ladybugs, nematodes, bats and birds.
- Cover your organic vegetables-Spunbound Polyester Rowcover keeps out pests but allows light, air & water to get through.
- Spray neem oil - Oils & seeds from the neem tree have been used in
  India for centuries. It's a great, low-toxicity insecticide &
  fungicide.
- Spray vinegar - Spray household vinegar on your weeds. The acidic water kills them 
  especially on sunny days.
- Use botanical insecticide-Pyrethrum spray or dust is made from a
  daisy-like flower grown in Kenya. The flower is ground into powder.
  It protects against ants, aphids, roaches, fleas & flies but is not
  good for cats.
- Weed your garden well and regularly to minimize hiding places for
  insect pests and to prevent the weeds from competing with your
  vegetables for water and nutrients.
- Remove infested plants to prevent the pests from spreading to
  neighboring plants.
- Place traps around the outside of your garden. Pheromone traps
  attract insects during their mating cycles, and yellow sticky traps
  are effective against flying insects such as aphids, whiteflies and
  fungus gnats.

Comment: Weeds and "rough" spots of native plants will help provide a year long environment for natural predators, a "sterile" cultivation is much more prone to plagues in my experience.

Answer (score 13):

The typical Permaculture approach is to cultivate habitat for animals that will eat the insects.  It is hard to say without knowing more about the insects but if they are aphids, maybe ladybugs will be helpful.  If they are big beetles, maybe frogs and lizards.  And don't forget birds!

In general it is important to cultivate habitat first before trying to import such predators into your garden,  Without habitat, they will leave or die.  With habitat they will be more likely to call your garden home.  You may not even need to import any as they may come from all around to live.

This is a fairly general answer to a fairly general question, but it should get you started.  Of course you want to start by finding out what sorts of predators might be appropriate and where they live.  Note pesticides may work in the short term but they tend to kill off predators early and prevent predators from being able to long-term effectively control the pests.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking about plants planted in the **bucket** (?).

Actually these plants need direct sunlight (but not too much) and fresh air, as well as water. You can put it in shade in a terrace.

1. And while watering the plant, be careful that you are not giving too much water, which will spoil the health of that plant.
2. And as much as possible, keep plants together, but in different pots.
3. Also plant healthy plants. Remove previous unhealthy plants from the pot.